# Why my jwt authentication microservice return unauthorized?

Tags: jwt, jhipster

I'm trying to create a authentication Microservice application using Jhipster 6.1.2 like in the monolithic application. I'generated a User and a Authority entites and added Services and Rest Controllers and the csv files like in the monolithic application.

I launched the jhipster registry and my authentication microservice locally. Then in the JHipster Registry I went to Administration -> API and I selected my authentication microservice API.

Then in the User JWT Controller when I made a POST request to /api/authenticate with the following parameters:  `{"password":"admin","username":"admin"}` 
I received Response Code 401 with a Response Body:

```
{
  "type": "jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title": "Unauthorized",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Bad credentials",
  "path": "/api/authenticate",
  "message": "error.http.401"
}
```

I tried to register a new user. I went to Account Resource and I made a POST request to /api/register with the following parameters:

```
 {
    "login": "user9",
    "password": "user9",
    "email": "user9@localhost",
    "firstName": "User9",
    "lastName": "User9",
    "imageUrl": "",
    "langKey": "en"
}
```

I received Response Code 201
I checked my database and the user is added. Then in the Account Resource, I activated this user with a GET request to /api/activate I received a Response Code 200 OK.

Then I went again to the User JWT Controller and I tried to authenticate with the new user `{"password":"user9","username":"user9"}` I still got the Response Code 401 Unauthorized.

**The problem:**

I can register and activate a user but I can't login with the  default User csv file and even with a new user.

**Questions:**

How to use the default User csv file to login ?

Is it a problem with the base64-secret ?

**Error Console:**

> org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException:
>   Bad credentials   at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:151)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175)
>     at
>   **com.mycompany.account.web.rest.UserJWTController.authorize(UserJWTController.java:60)**
>     at
>   com.mycompany.account.web.rest.UserJWTController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$793feb43.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.account.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:86)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.account.web.rest.UserJWTController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$610c10a6.authorize()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.account.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:38)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Did you copy your JWT secret key to the registry? See https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#securing-jwt

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Yes, both applications use the same base64-secret key in the application-dev.yml file.

Comment: The application-dev.yml of your microservice is not read, its configuration must be served by the registry from the `central-config/*.yml` files. https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/blob/master/central-config/application.yml

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thank you but it still does not work 
In the JHipster Registry I went to central-config/application.yml and 
I changed the secret property to base64-secret but I still got the Response Code 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: You restarted the microservice after that, right? If anything fails, then run under debugger and put a breakpoint in TokenProvider and find what's wrong. You are lucky to have a very reproductible problem so it should not be very hard to solve.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou the problem is with this line `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginVM.getUsername(), loginVM.getPassword());` the code stop here and throw a BadCredentialsException.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou this is the output : 

1-getUsername: user1

2-getPassword: user1

3-authenticationToken:
 org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@1f: Principal: user1; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: null; Not granted any authorities
2019-08-03 13:04:45.815 ERROR 13840 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] c.m.account.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Exception in com.mycompany.account.web.rest.UserJWTController.authorize() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'Bad credentials'

Comment: Logs won't help, run it under debugger, step through spring security or jhipster code (probably TokenProvider) and check the variables values at the location where the exception is thrown not where it is caught. Here you come too late without any details.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I'm really trying. I set a breakpoint in the 
on the authorize() method in the UserJWTController the code stops before even calling `tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, rememberMe);`       this`authenticationManagerBuilder.getObject().authenticate(authenticationToken)` line throws the BadCredentialsException. The **authenticationToken**, **tokenProvider and the **authenticationManagerBuilder** variables contains some values.

Comment: This seems normal because your microservice does not create the token (it's the gateway's responsibility), it just extracts it from HTTP header, validates its signature against the JWT secret, checks expiration date and parses it to extract subject and authorithies. The exception should show you where it was thrown from in its stack trace, this is where you put the breakpoint or if you prefer you could set an exception breakpoint on BadCredentialsException type.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I added a BadCredentialsException Breakpoint. the debug enters AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.class then in the authenticate() method, the getUserFromCache return null, the try block contains a retrieveUser which return null and the UsernameNotFoundException catch block contains a If Statement hideUserNotFoundExceptions which throw a new BadCredentialsException.

Comment: Does it happen in gateway or service? This happens after token has been validated, what's the username ?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou The code calls the `authenticate(Authentication authentication)` method. the authentication variable contains {authenticated=false, authorities=[], credentials="user2", details=null, principal="user2"}
Then in this method set username="user2" , cacheWasUsed=false, user=null
The LoginVM contains {username='user2', rememberMe=true}
The TokenProvider contains {tokenValidityInMilliseconds=86400000, tokenValidityInMillisecondsForRememberMe=2592000000, JHipsterProperties, key..} 
It's before validation and token creation. before createToken and validateToken methods.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou ok ty anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing some files in the repository and in the security package and in the errors package. 
I followed the monolithic project and everything is working properly.